# Javascript to jumble up input box value

Tags: javascript, events, input, bookmarklet

Ok, I am writing some code which someone can use as a bookmarklet to jumble up an input box value in real time...

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var ii = 0; ii < elements.length; ii++) {

    elements[ii].addEventListener("keyup", function() {

        var input = elements[ii].value;
        var a = [""];
        var gen;
        for (x in input) {
            a[x] = input[input.length - x - 1];
        };
        for (x in a) {
            var gen = gen + a[x];
        };
        output = gen.replace('undefined', '');
        elements[ii].value = output;
    }, false);
};
```

This code (with JavaScript: in front) doesn't have affect on any input boxes. Can anyone see why?

Thanks!

Comment: use `this` in the listener instead of `elements[ii]`

Comment: Are you just trying to reverse the word?

Comment: @raghavv no, it's supposed to jumble it up as the user is typing in. My problem was that there was no effect on the text. But it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a few fixes in your code. Here is the modified version:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var ii = 0; ii < elements.length; ii++) {

    elements[ii].addEventListener("keyup", function() {

        var input = this.value;
        var a = [];
        var gen;
        for (var x in input) {
            a[x] = input[input.length - x - 1];
        };
        for (x in a) {
            var gen = gen + a[x];
        };
        output = gen.replace('undefined', '');
        this.value = output;
    }, false);
};
```

please check [demo](http://jsbin.com/utedek/2/watch)

Comment: Now that I look at this again, other than the `undefined`, isn't all of this the same as  `this.value = this.value.split('').reverse().join('');`

Comment: Yes, this is how you would reverse it. That was my first question. Your reverse logic is perfect. Besides, there is no need of 'undefined' check. There is nothing 'undefined' I have seen.

Comment: If you saw no `undefined` when why did you do `output = gen.replace('undefined', '');`? This is because the _for..in_ is unfiltered; it includes all the enumerable properties on the object and it's prototype chain.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` instead of  `elements[ii]` inside the addEventListener code.
Cos  elements[ii] will have no meaning inside that code.

Comment: Hmmm still doesn't work. I'll keep looking around. Thanks anyway!